# Set timeout for WiniumDriver in Winium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, winium

I'm working on a Winium project in the Java flavour.

How do I set the default timeout? The default one is really long.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/pull/71/commits/9e6672a9144c91b5c752a5e3b0afda29fb7499c5) helps you?

Comment: I saw this indeed but I don't know how to use it...

Answer (score -1):

I always put this way in a class called AbstractPageObject or as you like to call yourself.

```
public static void sleep() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    };

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not helping.